# Pandas Create Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create new dataframe with using pandas. The table has value name and how many row that value appear

In SQL I can create the table that I want like this

```sql
SELECT start_station_name, COUNT(*) as total_number
FROM table
GROUP BY start_station_name;
```

But when I used Pandas with assign function I tried in this way

```py
casual_station_name = pd.DataFrame().assign(station_name = casual_filter['start_station_name'], total_ride = casual_filter['start_station_name'].value_counts() )
```

But I can not do what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that in pandas dataframe by using `groupby` method:

```
casual_station_name = df.groupby(['start_station_name'])['start_station_name'].count()
```

Comment: I want to sort the result descending order, but how can I do

Comment: @Cornelias just use method `sort_values(ascending=False)` after the `count` method

Answer (score 0):

You can directy pass the data (as a dictionary) while creating the `dataFrame`:

```
casual_station_name = pd.DataFrame(dict(station_name = casual_filter['start_station_name'], total_ride = casual_filter['start_station_name'].value_counts()))
```

---

Source:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-create-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: I tried like this column1 = dataframe["start_station_name"].unique(), column2 = dataframe["start_station_name"].value_counts() and convert them to first dictionary then dataframe but I got "array length 1592 does not match index length 1591" error like this

Comment: Probably the size of the arrays is the not same (this will raise an error while creating the columns). I cannot verify this in the input code given.